# How to create JNDI for Unittests with Spring from XML Configuration?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jndi

Is there a simple way to configure a JNDI Environment for Unittests from a Spring XML File and export some stuff (e.g. Datasources)? There is [SimpleNamingContextBuilder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) for that, but this would require code to set up the JNDI Environment, and I would like to be able to just include an XML file into the @ContextConfiguration .

Comment: You want different datasources for unit testing than for production?

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys Of course. But the main point is that in production the application server sets up the JNDI, but here the Unittest itself.

Comment: We use Spring 3.1 bean profiles to do this

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys You mean using the profile replaces the JNDI dependent beans by other beans to avoid the use of JNDI? True, that's sometimes a better solution, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [SimpleJNDI](http://code.google.com/p/osjava/wiki/SimpleJNDI). You can get it from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Csimple-jndi%7Csimple-jndi%7C0.11.4.1%7Cjar).

Comment: This project is not under active development anymore. There is a GitHub clone with bug fixes and some new features maintained by me. See https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI .

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you can avoid the underlying problem to this question by these solutions:

- Use [Spring profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) to encapsulate the JNDI references into a profile and use another profile in JUnit-Tests that declares the replacements. (A little annoying here is that you introduce test related stuff into the production configu[ration files.)
- After the XML-configuration files you include in the Unittests another XML-configuration file that overrides the bean definitions that declare JNDI-references.

An advantage of these workarounds is that you avoid JVM-wide constructs like JNDI that might accidentially live longer than the test and do not allow parallel execution of the tests.